# How to locate the button element using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to find the xpath of the help button for my automation tests.
Here is the HTML element:

```
<button data-component-id="nokia-react-components-iconbutton" tabindex="0" class="ActionComponent__ActionComponentDiv-sc-st3635-0 iPWdbh IconButton__StyledButton-sc-1dtic80-0 biWRLS NSPAppBanner__HelpButton-sc-761pc0-3 dvtRqt" mode="dark" type="button" xpath="1"></button>
<svg class="HelpOutline__NSPSvgIcon-sc-7y3t1-0 geSzXs HelpWidget__StyledHelp-sc-1fdz44x-0 cCTbqa" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xpath="1">
</svg>
```

I tried with this XPath, but it didn't work:

```
//*[@data-component-id="nokia-react-components-iconbutton"]//svg[contains(@class,"HelpOutline")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the `<button>` element before the `<svg>`, try the following XPath:

```
//*[@data-component-id="nokia-react-components-iconbutton" and following-sibling::svg[1][contains(@class,"HelpOutline")]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element itself should be clickable and both the [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) should work:

- [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

  ```
  button[class*='HelpButton'][data-component-id='nokia-react-components-iconbutton']
  ```
- [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

  ```
  //button[@data-component-id='nokia-react-components-iconbutton' and contains(@class, 'HelpButton')]
  ```

---

However, as the element is a [React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890212/scraping-a-react-table-using-selenium/62890615#62890615) element so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *Java* and *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-component-id='nokia-react-components-iconbutton' and contains(@class, 'HelpButton')]"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and *css_selector*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='HelpButton'][data-component-id='nokia-react-components-iconbutton']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: For Python clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Try this XPath to locate button:

```
'//*[name()="svg" and contains(@class,"HelpOutline")]/preceding-sibling::button'
```

Note that `svg` tag is not a part of standard HTML-namespace, so `//svg` won't work. You need to use `//*[name()="svg"]` instead